# Clojure idiom for dynamic map creation

Tags: clojure

I want to create a map based on variable inputs where a key should only be present if its corresponding value is not `nil`.

Here's a toy example I came up with:

```
(defn make-map
  [foo bar baz]
  (-> {}
      (into (and foo {:foo foo}))
      (into (and bar {:bar bar}))
      (into (and baz {:baz baz}))))
```

Is there a more accepted/idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: This will fail to associate values of `false`, if that matters (it isn't nil, but is still caught by the `and` calls)

Comment: True.  `false` is OK to skip, but if it weren't I could change eg. the `foo` to `(not (nil? foo))`.

Comment: `(some? x)` is equivalent to `(not (nil? x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses [cond->](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/cond-%3E) to simplify things a little.

```
(defn make-map
  [foo bar baz]
  (cond-> {}
    foo (assoc :foo foo)
    bar (assoc :bar bar)
    baz (assoc :baz baz)))
```

It's hard to tell with the toy example whether there's a better option for you.

Comment: this will fail to associate any key if the value is `false`

Comment: Nice!  I didn't know about `cond->`.  Seems to fit my situation pretty much exactly.

Answer (score 3):

I think something like this is a bit more straightforward

```
(defn make-map
   [foo bar baz]
   (reduce (fn [m [k v]] (if (some? v) (assoc m k v) m))
           {}
           {:foo foo :bar bar :baz baz}))

user> (make-map 1 nil 2)
{:baz 2, :foo 1}
user> (make-map nil 1 2)
{:baz 2, :bar 1}
user> (make-map true false true)
{:baz true, :bar false, :foo true}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could abstract this to use a syntax and application similar to zipmap so you can have variable argument lists for both keys and args

```
(defn when-zip
  [keys args]
  (->> args
       (map vector keys)
       (remove (comp not second))
       (into {})))

(when-zip [:foo :bar :baz :qux] [true nil false 1])
=> {:qux 1, :foo true}
```

When you don't like the creation of intermediate lazy results you can use Clojure 1.7's transducers or blatantly rip off `zipmap`'s source

```
(defn when-zip
  "Returns a map with each of the keys mapped to
   the corresponding val when val is truthy."
  [keys vals]
  (loop [map {}
         ks (seq keys)
         vs (seq vals)]
    (if (and ks vs)
      (recur (if-let [v (first vs)] 
               (assoc map (first ks) v)
               map)
             (next ks)
             (next vs))
      map)))

(when-zip [:foo :bar :baz :qux] [true nil false 1])
=> {:qux 1, :foo true}
```

If you really still need the original syntax you could then use this to define specific versions

```
(defn make-map
  [& args]
  (when-zip [:foo :bar :baz :qux] args))

(make-map true nil false 1)
 => {:qux 1, :foo true}
```

On the other hand, you could just not bother with removing nils and use `zipmap`; when you do a map lookup on a non-existing key further on, it will give the same result as a key with value nil anyway:

```
(:baz {:qux 1, :foo true})
=> nil
(:baz {:qux 1, :baz nil, :bar false :foo true})
=> nil
```

Of course, this is different with `:bar`. But usually it's better to do `nil` and `false` punning at the consuming stage instead of during transformation.

Comment: There is no case where `(boolean (not x))` is different from `(not x)`.

Answer (score 1):

For a little bit of variety, a generalisation using `for`:

```
(defn some-map
  [& args]
  (->> (for [[k v] (partition 2 args)
             :when (some? v)]
         [k v])
       (into {})))
```

Usage:

```
(some-map :a 1 :b 2 :c nil :d false)
;; => {:a 1, :b 2, :d false}
```

Or, akin to @noisesmith's answer, something to be applied to an existing map:

```
(defn some-map
  [m]
  (into {} (filter (comp some? val) m)))

(some-map {:a 1 :b 2 :c nil :d false})
;; => {:b 2, :d false, :a 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn make-map [foo bar baz]
    (into {} 
         (filter 
              #(if-not (nil? (second %)) { (first %) (second %)})
              (map vector [ :foo :bar :baz] [for bar baz]))
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, here's something closer to what I was trying to reach for originally but didn't quite get.

```
(defn make-map
  [foo bar baz]
  (apply hash-map
         (concat
          (and foo [:foo foo])
          (and bar [:bar bar])
          (and baz [:baz baz]))))
```